# Haters will say 28 June

Tags: number-sequence, number-property

Find the next number in this sequence:

> $4,3,7,5,10,15,?$

Think outside the frustum here.

Hint 1:

> This has to do with a ratio that is of a kind that Pythagoras and his followers didn’t like.

Hint 2:

> The title is double the key to the puzzle.

Comment: How relevant is the title?

Comment: @Brandon_J  Very relevant :)

Comment: I am thinking that it has linkages to rot13 (Uvccnfhf naq Veengvbany Ahzoref) but I could not decipher the link to the title yet

Comment: @Kryesec think of ratios

Comment: I wish I saw hints when I posted lmao.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the answer:

> 9?
>  Using Hint 2, the key to the puzzle is $\pi$ since $(\dfrac{1}{2} * 6.28 = 3.14)$.
>  Comparing the differences between the nth digit of the sequence and the nth digit of pi results in the natural numbers $1,2,3,...$. As such, the next digit is the 7th digit of $\pi$ plus 7, which is $2+7=9$.

Comment: You got it, well done! 

Answer (score 4):

This may be too obvious, but a possible answer is:

> 6

Reasoning:

> Given that 4+3=7 and 5+10=15, the sequence can be interpreted in the form of advancing triplets of the form a+b=c. Since a in each triplet goes up by one, that gives 6 as the next value.

Comment: No, but that’s an interesting coincidence that is really cool once you know the rule. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> 13. 4,x,7,x,10,x,13? Just a thought!

Comment: No, use the subtle hints. :)

Comment: @ArvasuKulkarni is 13 the correct answer?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode No.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution. I do not have very much basis to give this answer, but I thought I would throw it out there.

Sorry if this is incorrect.

> Given that the series is 4,3,7,5,10,15,?,
>  And 4+3=7, 7+5-2=10,
>  Would the next item be 10+15-4=21?

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was too obvious but I don't know.

> How about 12? Both the addition and subtraction seem to go up.
>  4-1, 7-2. 
>  3+4, 5+5, 10+5.
>  I was thinking that the amount of addition was going up by one each time.
>  So, as if it was going: Take once, Add once, Take once, Add twice, take once.
>  The next digit would then be 18, if I'm right?

Comment: There are 2 numbers? Beware spoilers in my comment 12 and 18

Comment: What’s the relevance of the title here?